# Python Pandas - New column grouping and mode

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the next dataframe

```
A | B | C
---------
1 | 22 | 12
2 | 22 | 5
2 | 22 | 5
3 | 23 | 6
```

I want to add a new column called D to this dataframe. The value of D should be the most repeated value of C (mode) grouping by A and B.

I try with this

```
def mode(x):
    return mstats.mode(x, axis=None)[0]

df_total['D'] = df_total.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'C': mode})
```

but i have the next error

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform(lambda x: scipy.stats.mode(x)[0][0])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with [`pd.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html). The difficulty is that `pd.Series.mode` returns a series rather than a scalar. It's not considered a "reducing" function. Therefore, you must extract the first value of the series.

Data from @gyoza.

```
df['D'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])

print(df)

   A   B   C   D
0  1  22  12  12
1  2  22   5   5
2  2  22   5   5
3  2  22   3   5
4  3  23   6   6
```